# Alarm not setting correctly using AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am fairly new to android development and my capstone project team wants to have our project controlled by an android app alarm. 
I followed some guides online for starter code and I can get the app to open and all the buttons to work, but the alarm itself is not triggering. 
I used

```
String nextAlarm = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
```

and logcat to show the alarm, after it is set, and the alarm that I just set does not show up, rather the one for tomorrow morning is shown.

Here is my main method:

```
public class pancake_alarm extends Activity {

AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private TimePicker alarmTimePicker;
private static pancake_alarm inst;
private TextView alarmTextView;

int pancake_quant = 0;

public static pancake_alarm instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pancake_alarm);
    alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
    alarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmText);
    ToggleButton alarmToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    final Button OneButton;
    final Button TwoButton;
    final Button ThreeButton;
    final Button FourButton;

    OneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one_button);
    OneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pancake_quant = 1;
        }
    });

    TwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two_button);
    TwoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pancake_quant = 2;
        }
    });

    ThreeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three_button);
    ThreeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pancake_quant =3;
        }
    });

    FourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four_button);
    FourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pancake_quant = 4;
        }
    });
}

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // for debugging
    String str = "TAG";
    Log.v(str, "Toggle Clicked");

    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm On");
        // Update pancake quantity string
        setPancakeQuant(pancake_quant);
        setPancakeTime(1);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getHour());
            Log.v(str, "Finding Hour, SDK 23+");
        }else {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
            Log.v(str, "Finding Hour, SDK < 23");
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getMinute());
            Log.v(str, "Finding Minute, SDK 23+");
        }else {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            Log.v(str, "Finding Minute, SDK < 23");
        }
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(pancake_alarm.this, AlarmReciever.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(pancake_alarm.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        Log.v(str, "Well it got to this fuckin line at least");
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        String nextAlarm = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
        Log.v(str, nextAlarm);
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        setAlarmText("");
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
        // Update pancake quantity string
        setPancakeQuant(0);
        setPancakeTime(0);
    }

}
```

I can post my reciever and service as well, but since it doesn't seem to even be getting to them I dont know if they are useful.

Am I missing somethign obvious here?

Thanks!

edit: here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.javapapers.androidalarmclock">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dustin.pancake_alarm.pancake_alarm"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name="com.example.dustin.pancake_alarm.AlarmService"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <receiver android:name="com.example.dustin.pancake_alarm.AlarmReciever" />
</application>
```

Comment: `NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED` isn't going to show that alarm you've set in your code. Do you have a `<receiver>` element in your manifest for `AlarmReciever`?

Comment: I have alarmreciever in receiver in the manifest for the main activity, but do i need manifests for the receiver and service as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you. You only have one manifest. Beyond that, you need a `<receiver>` element for `AlarmReciever`, and a `<service>` element for the `Service` class. These elements must be inside the `<application>` tags, but not inside any others. Also, make sure everything is spelled correctly, as your IDE might not say anything if the spelling doesn't match the actual class names. If you want, you can [edit] your question to post the manifest, and we can have a look.

Comment: ah i see. Sorry I am new to this so i was confused. Manifest posted

Comment: No worries. That all looks good. If you're getting the log prints you expect in setting the alarm, then I would have to think that it's not being set at the time you might think. How are you determining if the Receiver and Service run? If it's just log prints, then make sure you're not missing them, as an alarm set for any past time will fire immediately. In fact, I would suggest that you test the alarm without the `TimePicker` for the moment, and just set it for `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: ill give that a try, thanks!

Comment: this worked, thanks! I was setting it incorrectly before, and this helped me find the error. thanks!